# Is subtraction of two symmetric and idempotent matrices still idempotent and symmetric?

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ which are both symmetric and idempotent,
is the sum or subtraction of this two matrices still symmetric and idempotent?

Comment: Not in general. We can have $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$ but $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + AB + BA + B^2$ which is only equal to $A^2+B^2$ when $AB=BA=0$. I think the identity matrix serves as a counterexample.

Comment: Try it for yourself: expand the square of this sum or product and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

The sum or difference is still symmetric, but it need not be idempotent. The identity matrix is easily seen to be a counterexample for the sum. If you look you can probably come up with one for the difference.